# How do I add a loop for scanf in C?

Tags: c

I have a short question:
How can I expand my program so that it checks if I entered the right format?... if not the program should repeat the scanf.

This is how far I came:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float zahlen[2];
    int i = 0;

        while (i < 2 && zahlen != EOF) {
            printf("%d. Zahl", i + 1);
            scanf_s("%f", &zahlen[i]);
        }


        printf("Division: %f\n", zahlen[0] / zahlen[1]);
        printf("Produkt: %f\n", zahlen[0] * zahlen[1]);
        printf("Summe: %f\n", zahlen[0] + zahlen[1]);
        printf("Diffenrenz: %f\n", zahlen[0] - zahlen[1]);
        printf("Mittelwert: %f\n", (zahlen[0] + zahlen[1]) / 2);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Would appreciate any help of you. Have a nice day/night.

Comment: Please tell more detail about your code. What is the "right format"? You mean that, you allow `float` only?

Comment: Read a _line_ of user input with `fgets()`, then convert to `float` with `strtof()`.

Comment: You need to read the return value coming from scanf_s to check if an input failure occurred.

Comment: @A.Godnov Yes exactly.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. It helped me alot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define what a right format is. But in a form of pseudo-code

```
float input;

// First get the input
do { 
    sacnf_s("%f", &input);
} while (!IsRightFormat(input));  // If the input was not correct get it again


// Do your stuff here
// ...
```

Comment: `float input; IsRightFormat(input)` cannot check if input is in the correct format.  It can only check values of `input`, if the `scanf_s()` was successful.